# Proxy server gets enabled

Tags: windows-7, proxy

Whenever I deselect "use a proxy server" in internet options, it stays deselected until I restart.  How do I prevent this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's a Group Policy setting, in which case, you need to speak to an Active Directory administrator to put you in a group that doesn't have this policy applied.

I suffered from it for a number of months before I finally got the change made (worse, mine reset roughly every hour and screwed up my Azure testing and deployment).

Comment: I'm not using a server or anything.  This is a home computer